# i need to put the grade calculation into a function and i really don't know where to start

Tags: python, csv

resetting values

```
name = []

score1 = []

score2 = []

t_list = []
```

Importing the CSV file and reading its contents

```
import csv

f = open ("Classmarks.csv")

rows = f.readlines()

for line in rows:

    line = line.strip()

    el = line.split (",")

    name = el[0]

    score1 = el[1]

    score2 = el[2]
```

calculating the percentage and using that to calculate the grade and adding the grade to t_list for later use. **This is the section I need to put into a function**

```
per = (float(score1) + float(score2) / 1.5)

if (per < 101) and (per >= 70):
    print(el[0] ,"Your Grade is an A with a percentage of", per , "%" , '')
    t_list.append("A")

elif (per < 70) and (per >= 60):
    print(el[0] ,"Your Grade is a B with a percentage of", per , "%"  , '')
    t_list.append("B")

elif (per < 60) and (per >= 50):
    print(el[0] , "Your grade is a C with a percentage of", per , "%"  , '')
    t_list.append("C")

elif (per < 50) and (per >= 45):
    print(el[0] ,"Your grade is a D with a percentage of", per , "%"  , '')
    t_list.append("D")

else:
    print(el[0] ,"You have Failed with a percentage of", per , "%" )
    t_list.append("F")
```

counting and printing the number of A grades achieved

```
print("there were" , t_list.count('A') , "A's achieved")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your loop like this. 
(Note: I removed the extra line breaks, to adhere to best Python coding practices)

```
for line in rows:
    line = line.strip()
    el = line.split (",")
    # All values should be added to the appropriate lists.
    # Before, your code was overwriting the name and score list 
    # variables with single values on each iteration of this for loop.
    name.append(el[0])
    score1.append(el[1])
    score2.append(el[2])
    # Here's where the magic happens
    calculateGrade(el)
```

Then add this function somewhere in your code base. I personally recommend putting it at the very end of this file (since it is the only function), but you could theoretically add it anywhere in this code base. Be sure to leave the last line out of the function (the line where you print the number of As).

```
def calculateGrade(el):
    # Your code goes here (be sure to add one extra indent to everything)
```

Putting it all together (once again, using best practices):

```
import csv
name = []
score1 = []
score2 = []
t_list = []
with open ("Classmarks.csv") as f:
    rows = f.readlines()
for line in rows:
    line = line.strip()
    el = line.split (",")
    name.append(el[0])
    score1.append(el[1])
    score2.append(el[2])
    calculateGrade(el)
print("there were" , t_list.count('A') , "A's achieved")

# Calculates the grades, prints them, and stores them in t_list
def calculateGrade(el):
    # score1 -> el[1] and score2 -> el[2], to match updated logic
    per = (float(el[1]) + float(el[2]) / 1.5)

    if (per < 101) and (per >= 70):
        # Note: The original code was printing an empty string at the
        # end of the line, which is functionally identical to this 
        # updated line (this is true for A - D cases)
        print(el[0] ,"Your Grade is an A with a percentage of", per , "%")
        t_list.append("A")

    elif (per < 70) and (per >= 60):
        print(el[0] ,"Your Grade is a B with a percentage of", per , "%")
        t_list.append("B")

    elif (per < 60) and (per >= 50):
        print(el[0] , "Your grade is a C with a percentage of", per , "%")
        t_list.append("C")

    elif (per < 50) and (per >= 45):
        print(el[0] ,"Your grade is a D with a percentage of", per , "%")
        t_list.append("D")

    else:
        print(el[0] ,"You have Failed with a percentage of", per , "%")
        t_list.append("F")
```

Answer (score 0):

After the

```
el = line.split ( "," )

def grade_count ( el_list, grade ): 
#then everything after
#sub the 'A' in the count in print statement with var grade
```

Call the function:

```
grade_count(el, 'A')
```

Now the function will print the number of defined grade.
Or you can make the function return the t_list

Also put the empty lists inside the function.
Score1, Score2, t_list